# How could i dynamically pass the following data as json to asyncHTTPClient?

Tags: android, json, android-async-http, asynchttpclient

{
        "Name”: ”ValidateUserName”,
        “Message”: 
    {
        ”UserName”: ”p”
    }
    }

How could i make these parameters to json format to dynamically pass the parameters to AsyncHTTPClient post method.

Using below method gives a wrong json output

```
HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
JSONObject jsonvalue =new JSONObject();
         try {
            jsonvalue.put("Name","ValidateUserName");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         try {
            jsonvalue.put("Message",param);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output:**
    {
    "Name":"ValidateUserName",
    "Message":"
    {
    UserName=amsecmobileuser
    }
    "
   }

Could anyone say why the output is not as expected.......

Comment: Create another JSONObject just for the params and then add that to jsonValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create another JSONObject for Message. try this:

```
    HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
    param.put("username", "p");
    JSONObject jsonvalue = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonvalue.put("Name", "ValidateUserName");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        JSONObject messageObj = new JSONObject();
        messageObj.put("UserName", param.get("username"));
        jsonvalue.put("Message", messageObj);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: But by this method if we have 10 nested loops we should create 10 separate objects.....do we have any 3rd party libraries to convert to correct json format the data

Comment: i am not sure, but theres this library called Jackson. may be that'll do the trick.